# AzureFileCopy@3 equivalent on Linux agent

Tags: azure-pipelines

I'm using a `window` based agent in Azure Pipeline. One of the task is to copy over an artifact to an Azure Blob Storage.

```
- task: AzureFileCopy@3
  displayName: 'Upload to Azure'
  inputs:
     sourcePath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/dist'
     azureSubscription: 'My Subscription'
     destination: 'AzureBlob'
     storage: $(featureStorageName)
     containerName: '$web'
```

Microsoft suggest to use `az storage blob` with `task: AzureCLI@2`

> This task is written in PowerShell and thus works only when run on
> Windows agents. If your pipelines require Linux agents and need to
> copy files to an Azure Storage Account, consider running az storage
> blob commands in the Azure CLI task as an alternative.

#### Question

What would be the equivalent command that I can run on a `Linux` agent?

I think the skeleton would start like:

```
task: AzureCLI@2
inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'My Subscription'
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
    az ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be something like this :

```
variables:
  storageAccountName: 'test' #Your storage account name
  containerName: 'test' #The container name which you want to copy files to

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'My Subscription'
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: 'az storage blob upload-batch --destination $(containerName) --account-name $(storageAccountName) --source $(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a try with :

`inlineScript: 'az storage blob upload --account-name MyStorageAccount --account-key 0000-0000 -f "path/to/file" -c MyContainer -n NewBlob'`

You could refer to [az storage azcopy blob upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/azcopy/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-azcopy-blob-upload-examples) for more information.

Comment: @Léo Coco, is there any updates for this question? Please feel free to let me know whether the answers below can help you and feel free to comment~ Just a remind to [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 0):

It took me too much time to resolve this and I somehow ended up here so I'm leaving my answer as a sign of hope to others that were lost. As for 2023 there is [an answer on github](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/8920#issuecomment-1556180898) that works best with azcopy, but only when you change network settings to allow traffic from your machine performing the upload.